# reportviewer parameter list not formatted correctly

Tags: parameters, webforms, reporting-services

In my reportviewer for webforms, the text for a multi-drop down parameter list appears underneath the checkbox instead of to the right of the value.

My ssrs rpt shows the values to the right, but when accessing the ssrs rpt from the server via my webform app, they appear under each other.

How can I set this where the text appears to the right instead of under each other?

Example:

```
checkbox
AAA
checbox
BBB
checkbox
CCC

checkbox AAA
checkbox BBB
checkbox CCC
```

My reportviewer markup is set up as the following:rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1"

```
runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
    Font-Size="10pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Tahoma" WaitMessageFont-Size="10pt" Height="667px" 
    Width="1241px" ShowFindControls="true" ShowExportControls="true" ShowPrintButton="true">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="/wms_reports/crewzfone_sales" 
        ReportServerUrl="http://ojuscluster01/reportserver" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I placed the following override style onto the webpage, but appears not to be taking place:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown
    {
        text-align: left !important;
        overflow: visible;
    }
</style>
```

The pagesource is as follows... You can see the dropdown on the DIV tag with the table data after that. Each one is a checkbox (which is fine), but like I mentioned, the assoiciated data appears ON TOP OF EACH CHECKBOX INSTEAD OF IMMEDIATELY TO THE RIGHT OF THE CHECKBOX.

There doesn't appear any way to change the style on the reportviewer at all via any properties other than what I did in the page above. If anybody has run into this same issue and resolved it, I would appreciate hearing from you very much.

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="display:inline-block;border-color:DarkGray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:8pt;height:150px;overflow:auto;background-color:window;display:none;position:absolute;z-index:11;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:window;">
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Chart1$rptViewerCrewzFoneSales$ctl04$ctl03$divDropDown$ctl00" onclick="$get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03&#39;).control.OnSelectAllClick(this);" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl00">(Select All)</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Chart1$rptViewerCrewzFoneSales$ctl04$ctl03$divDropDown$ctl01" onclick="$get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03&#39;).control.OnValidValueClick(this, $get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl00&#39;));" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl01">AZM</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl02" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Chart1$rptViewerCrewzFoneSales$ctl04$ctl03$divDropDown$ctl02" onclick="$get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03&#39;).control.OnValidValueClick(this, $get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl00&#39;));" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl02">CCL</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl03" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Chart1$rptViewerCrewzFoneSales$ctl04$ctl03$divDropDown$ctl03" onclick="$get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03&#39;).control.OnValidValueClick(this, $get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl00&#39;));" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl03">CEL</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl04" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Chart1$rptViewerCrewzFoneSales$ctl04$ctl03$divDropDown$ctl04" onclick="$get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03&#39;).control.OnValidValueClick(this, $get(&#39;ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl00&#39;));" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_Chart1_rptViewerCrewzFoneSales_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl04">CRY</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
```

Comment: I would like to see more ability to customise the parameter bar.

Comment: I defintely agree... I'm stuck with the way the parameters are formatted. No matter what I try and do with the styleing, I can't get it to display the way I want it. Any other suggestions from anybody would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I've never played in the xml scource code but in sying that the parameter box in report is setup and formatted automatically.

I don't believe your going to get this out. :(  I hope I'm wrong as I would like to be able to format the parameter box.

See this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx) for details.

Comment: Yes, I see... This makes sense viewing the rpt directly from SSRS, which is formatted just fine. However, when using the reportviewer control in a webforms app, the parameters are formatted differently than the ssrs version and I can't get them to display properly like I previoulsy mentioned. Any help from anybody else would be much appreciated...

Comment: fyi, while using IE, the parameters were automatically formatted correctly, but not in Firefox..... Any ideas going forward with how I may be able to get the parameter list formatted correctly with FireFox?

Comment: fyi, IE seems like the only browser that will format the parameter list correctly. While using Chrome, the dropdownlist was formatted just like IE, but did not have any Calendar selections to select dates. How can we as developers use the reportviewer successfully with the proper formatting for the other two browsers (FireFox & Chrome)?

Comment: It is a microsoft product ;)